# How to Webpack a multiple page (tsx) website with separate js files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I am using:

`react` for page rendering.

`typescript` **directly**(without babel) transpiling tsx to ES5 for browsers

`webpack` to generate codes separately

`babel-polyfill` to be packaged in the `vendor.js` but not referenced by typescript codes

I want to package javascript libraries and my common codes into one `vendor.js` and generate **separately** `[name].js` files with `[name].html` (with template) referencing both `vendor.js` and `[name].js` for each `[name].tsx` (which conatins **only** a class definition `[name]` that extends `React.Component<P,S>`) with `HtmlWebpackPlugin`.

`[name].tsx` may import modules. Modules included in `vendor.js` **cannot be included in `[name].js`**, and the others must be normally included in `[name].js`

I have read the document form `webpack` official site and still have no idea how to do it.

I did find some guides that realize a multiple page website but  having all libraries included in the separate `[name].js` files, which means the javascript libraries are redundantly included in every single `[name].js` and it is surely not expected.

And I found some guides about `externals`, but it can only be used on existing js files, not generated bundle files.

Here is my current `webpack.config.js` which supports only single page:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        "index.js": ['babel-polyfill', './src/index.tsx']
    },
    output: { filename: '[name]' },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./src/index.html"
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: '/node_modules/'
        }, {
            enforce: 'pre',
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'source-map-loader'
        },]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js', '.tsx']
    },
    devtool: "source-map"
}
```

Is there any way to have it support multiple pages as described?